# Prometheus different remote write configs

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, victoriametrics

I have 2 victoriametrics i would like to remote write metrics to from one prometheus. However, i only want some data written to one victoria and some other data written to the other (i don’t necessarily want all data to be sent).

Is there a way to write different metric relabel configs to the two different victorias I remote write to?

Comment: In Prometheus define two remote write destinations, each with unique `write_relabel_configs` - see https://gist.github.com/hagen1778/b073e80374d5b422a9d7687c5274e5ee
And update relabel config to drop time series which you don't want to be sent to a specific destination.